# Observing Android SQLite table

Tags: android, sqlite, su, rooted-device

I want to detect any change (insert/update/delete) in a 3rd party SQLite table of my device and communicate these changes to an external Rest API.

My device is rooted and I'm trying to implement a [Sync Adapter](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html) for sending those changes to the API.

These are my questions:

1. If I ask for android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER permission in the manifest, can I load any database of my device?
2. Can I create a Content Provider for this table using an URI like this one:

   URI_MY_TABLE = Uri.parse("sqlite:/data/data/com.my_package/my_db/db.db");